# Roots of a cubic

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I find the real root, I know I can say another root is (5+i) but would I use the product of the roots at all?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Complex roots always come in pairs via the conjugate, so you also know that $5-i$ is a root. Hence, you can factor your cubic to something like $$(x-(5+i))(x-(5-i))(x-A)$$ where $A$ is your yet-to-be determined real root. Expand the quantity $(x-(5+i))(x-(5-i))(x-A)$ and set it equal to $x^3+px^2+6x+q$. You can pattern match coefficients and should be able to solve for $A$ without too much difficulty.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks man

Answer (score 5):

There are two roots $5+i, 5-i$ because the coefficients are real and the roots come in complex conjugate pairs.

You can then use [Vieta's Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html), or simple expansion of $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, to note that if the roots are $a=5+i, b=5-i, c$ then $ab+ac+bc=26+5c+ic+5c-ic=26+10c=6$

This approach has the benefit of isolating the coefficient whose value you know, and simplifies equations at an earlier stage.

Answer (score 2):

Sum of roots = $ - p = 5 + i + 5 - i + U $; Unknown real root U = $ -p -10. $

Comment: This was my answer too, but then I realised that they want the actual value of the root (not just in terms of $p$ and $q$).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The following quadratic is a factor of your polynomial:

$$\begin{cases}&(5-i)(5+i)=|5-i|^2=26\\{}\\&5-i+5+i=10\end{cases}\;\;\implies (x-(5-i))(x-(5+i))=x^2-10x+26$$